# dotfuscator community edition

Tags: dotfuscator

I have been trying to use the dotfuscator community edition. I created a simple component with 1 method. I run it through the dotfuscator community edition in .net 2.0 by basically just choosing the .dll and clicking build. It appears to run. But when I use ILdasm to look at the .dll, I can still see the method name. I see several items as a,b,c,d,e... as well. But I still see my class name and method name. Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 10):

You should check if "Library" option is selected in Dotfuscator settings.

With that option active, Dotfuscator will NOT rename the public and protected methods of your assembly (to allow you or third party to use this assembly... while the inner method code is obfuscated).